# faced JDBC driver relate error while deploying artifact

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

```
15-Apr-2023 17:05:08.876 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/app] startup failed due to previous errors
15-Apr-2023 17:05:08.982 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [app] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

got above error during artifact deployment with spring framework in Intellij

my environments are
-zulu-11 jdk
-tomcat 9
-spring framework 5.3.22
-maven

the browser should be automatically starts when tomcat is started. but it doesn't. which means tomcat even don't start.
if I try to access the localhost:8080 on the browser there's nothing but 404 error page without any error message
It was worked very well until this suddenly gives this error and if I create a dynamic web project and tomcat would be started well. I really have no idea
All the answers will be appreciated.

put a ojdbc10.jar into TOMCAT_HOME/lib created many other project with same environment